# PostgreSQL convert varchar to numeric and get average

Tags: postgresql, average

I have a column that I want to get an average of, the column is varchar(200). I keep getting this error. How do I convert the column to numeric and get an average of it.

Values in the column look like

```
16,000.00
15,000.00
16,000.00 etc
```

When I execute

```
select CAST((COALESCE( bonus,'0')) AS numeric)
from tableone
```

... I get

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric:
```

Comment: Why on earth are you storing numbers in a `varchar` column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to represent (as text) a numeric in SQL is something like:

```
16000.00
15000.00
16000.00
```

So, your **commas** in the text are hurting you.

The most sensible way to solve this problem would be to store the data just as a `numeric` instead of using a string (`text`, `varchar`, `character`) type, as already suggested by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name).

However, assuming this is done for a good reason, such as you inherited a design you cannot change, one possibility is to get rid of all the characters which are not a (minus sign, digit, period) *before* casting to numeric:

Let's assume this is your input data

```
CREATE TABLE tableone
(
    bonus text
) ;

INSERT INTO tableone(bonus)
VALUES
    ('16,000.00'),
    ('15,000.00'),
    ('16,000.00'),
    ('something strange 25'),
    ('why do you actually use a "text" column if you could just define it as numeric(15,0)?'),
    (NULL) ;
```

You can remove all the straneous chars with a [`regexp_replace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) and the proper regular expression (`[^-0-9.]`), and do it `g`lobally:

```
SELECT
    CAST(
        COALESCE(
            NULLIF(
                regexp_replace(bonus, '[^-0-9.]+', '', 'g'), 
                ''),
            '0') 
       AS numeric)
FROM
    tableone ;
```

```
| coalesce |
| -------: |
| 16000.00 |
| 15000.00 |
| 16000.00 |
|       25 |
|      150 |
|        0 |
```

See what happens to the 15,0 (this may NOT be what you want).

Check everything at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=225dbc9f4d22045d3b2237202184dcc6)*

Comment: OK how do i get the average from your comment

Comment: You change `CAST(...)` to `avg(CAST(...))`. I.e., you use the [`avg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) aggregate function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that it might be because you have Empty strings rather than nulls in your column; this would result in the error you are seeing. Try wrapping the column name in a nullif:

`SELECT CAST(coalesce(NULLIF(bonus, ''), '0') AS integer) as new_field`

But I would really question your schema that you have numeric values stored in a varchar column...